# Erro ao renderizar com jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Informação rápida de como esse código deveria funcinar: Ajax pega um html, compila com Handlebars, o mesmo ajax pega um json de uma api, empacota tudo e renderiza num index com um append.

- **var orderTemplate** pega um templete do index.hbs
- **var temp** compila o orderTemplate para ser renderizado no index.hbs
- **function addOrder(order)** faz um **append** do template dentro do **index.hbs**

Na teoria, a requisição Ajax deveria pegar a **function addOrder(order)** e inserir no **index.hbs** junto com o **json** que a url do Ajax (url: '/api') também pega.
Porém na tela só aparece o Append do template, sem o conteúdo dentro.

Abaixo o código dentro do main.js:

```
var orderTemplate = $('#template-html').html();

var temp = Handlebars.compile(orderTemplate); 

function addOrder(order) {
    $orders.append(temp(order));    
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api',
    success: function(orders){
        $.each(orders, function(i, order){
            addOrder(order);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro ao listar :(');
    }
});
```

Abaixo é o template, que o **var orderTemplate = $('#template-html').html();** pega via id. Utilizo o Handlebars para renderizar.

```
<script  type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template-html">
   <div id='conteudo' class='row' data-id='{{_id}}'>
   <h4><span class="noedit nome">{{nome}}</span></h4>
   <p><span class="noedit nome">{{bebida}}</span></p>
   </div> 
</script>
```

Abaixo a foto do Append. Obs: O ajax consegue pegar o conteúdo buscado pela api e jogar no index.hbs, porém não consegue printar na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Segue abaixo uma foto de como o resultado final deveria ficar!
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço muito por quem leu e tentou ajudar. Fiz o possível para inserir o máximo de detalhes.

Comment: Tentou fazer isso :  `<h4><span class="noedit nome">{{order.nome}}</span></h4>` ?

Comment: `$orders.append(temp(order));` essa variavel `$orders` aqui não esta errada?

Comment: Já tentei sim fazer {{order.nome}} amigo

Comment: A variável $orders é essa: var $orders = $('#orders');
Ela é responsável por pegar uma div dentro do index. E além disso o append será colocado exatamente dentro dessa variável.
O que poderia estar errado? No resto do código ela funciona. Para Excluir, fazer update, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Era pra estar funcionando. Não da nenhum erro no console? A função `addOrder` ta realmente sendo chamada? Se você inspecionar o elemento `#orders` não tem nada? Parecem perguntas bestas, mas as vezes um detalhe passa despercebido.

Fiz um exemplo simples e funcionou certinho, segue abaixo:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #conteudo {
max-width: 250px;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 30px;
  }
</style>

<!-- DIV PRO APPEND -->
<div id="order"></div>

<!-- HTML HANDLEBARS -->
<script  type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template-html">
   <div id='conteudo' class='row' data-id='{{_id}}'>
   <h4><span class="noedit nome">{{nome}}</span></h4>
   <p><span class="noedit nome">{{bebida}}</span></p>
   </div>
</script>

<!-- SCRIPT "GET" E RENDERIZA -->
<script>

  var json = [{
      nome: 'Nome 1',
      bebida: 'Bebida 1',
      _id: '1'
  },
  {
      nome: 'Nome 2',
      bebida: 'Bebida 2',
      _id: '2'
  }
  ];

  var orderTemplate = $('#template-html').html();

  var temp = Handlebars.compile(orderTemplate);

  var $orders = jQuery('#order');

  function addOrder(order) {
  $orders.append(temp(order));
  }

  $.each(json, function(i, order) {
  addOrder(order);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Ótimo. Deu certo! Ah, outra dúvida Mateus...
Ali eu chamo o Handlebars com um link (<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>). Teria como eu usar o Handlebars do node? Porque se não fico usando dois handlebars, um só para fazer esses templates, e outro para renderizar conteúdo na tela.

Comment: Pode sem problemas, o handlebars do node, nada mais é que o mesmo arquivo  js. Ao colocar o link na página, você pode utilizar o path para arquivo que está na sua pasta do app.